# How to debug and resolve crashes of cargo-build-sbf?

Tags: build-sbf

It is possible to cause a crash of `cargo build-sbf`

For instance https://github.com/shepmaster/twox-hash disabling the default feature "std": `cargo build-sbf`

crashes with

`rustc --crate-name twox_hash ... (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)`

The core dump is

```
* thread #5, stop reason = ESR_EC_DABORT_EL0 (fault address: 0x5e1c00611645d8ca)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010866758c librustc_driver-1071ea70b4f3801e.dylib`llvm::MachineInstr::MachineInstr(llvm::MachineFunction&, llvm::MCInstrDesc const&, llvm::DebugLoc, bool) + 104
    frame #1: 0x000000010865b6e0 librustc_driver-1071ea70b4f3801e.dylib`llvm::MachineFunction::CreateMachineInstr(llvm::MCInstrDesc const&, llvm::DebugLoc, bool) + 108
    frame #2: 0x0000000107bfeab0 librustc_driver-1071ea70b4f3801e.dylib`llvm::SBFInstrInfo::expandMEMCPY(llvm::MachineInstrBundleIterator<llvm::MachineInstr, false>) const + 416
    frame #3: 0x0000000107bff234 librustc_driver-1071ea70b4f3801e.dylib`llvm::SBFInstrInfo::expandPostRAPseudo(llvm::MachineInstr&) const + 32
    frame #4: 0x000000010859a190 librustc_driver-1071ea70b4f3801e.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::ExpandPostRA::runOnMachineFunction(llvm::MachineFunction&) + 244
```

I am not sure if this is a bug as it should give an error rather than crash, or if this is how it is supposed to do when compiling something it doesn't support.

Comment: Considering it's a crash in `llvm::SBFInstrInfo::expandMEMCPY`, it looks like a compiler bug! I did find the source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/llvm-project/blob/7b8db05b564faffb522434b73b7082662171f94a/llvm/lib/Target/SBF/SBFInstrInfo.cpp#L45 -- your best bet will be to file a GitHub issue.